# Unable to click on an element though lt is available on the Web Page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Unable to click on element though Web driver is able to find it.

Already implicit wait applied. Also,tried explicit wait but when explicit wait getting error element is not attached to page

```
WebElement sales_order_doc_type_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='WD67']"));
sales_order_doc_type_dropdown.click();
```

HTML Code for element

```html
<input id="WD67" ct="CB" lsdata="{1:'26.4ex',5:true,8:'WD68',9:'1'}" lsevents="{Select:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}]}" type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="urEdf2TxtEnbl lsEdfLeftBrdRadius lsEdf3TxtHlpBtn urBorderBox lsControl--explicitwidth" readonly="" value="" style="vertical-align:top;width:26.4ex;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id^='WD'][ct='CB'][lsevents*='ClientAction']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'WD') and @ct='CB'][contains(@lsevents, 'ClientAction')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: When try explicit wait getting error - stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: I used Actions to click and it is working                                                          
         Actions action = new Actions(driver);
       action.moveToElement(sales_order_doc_type_dropdown);
       action.click().perform();